# DateTime.plusMinutes(..) return minutes -1

Tags: java, jodatime

I am encountering a problem using JodaTime. Here is my method:

```
public double calculateTimeDifference(String startedAt) {
    DateTime cet = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("CET"));

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    DateTime convertedStartedAt = formatter.parseDateTime(startedAt);

    Period period = new Interval(cet, convertedStartedAt).toPeriod();
    int minutes = period.getMinutes();

    return minutes;
}
```

And I have a test that adds 30 minutes to the time:

```
@Test
public void testTimeDifference() {
    DateTime testtime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("CET")).plusHours(2);
    testtime = testtime.plusMinutes(30);

    // Format for input
    DateTimeFormatter cet = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    // Parsing the date
    DateTime requestedFormat = cet.parseDateTime(testtime.toString());
    // Format for output
    DateTimeFormatter requestedTime = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    double time = carService.calculateTimeDifference(requestedTime.print(requestedFormat));

    assertEquals(30, time, 0.0);
}
```

But when I run this the output is:

```
Expected : 30.0
Actual : 29.0
```

Comment: "Here is my method" Is this `carService.calculateTimeDifference`? Please show an [mcve], rather than making us guess how these fit together.

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that @AndyTurner

Comment: "`DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("CET"));`" Well, that's a confusing name :) In general, I would say that you're doing too much conversion here: date times to strings to date times to intervals to periods. There is bound to be some loss of precision in there.

Comment: For example, why `new Interval(utc, convertedStartedAt).toPeriod()`, rather than `new Period(utc, convertedStartedAt)`?

Comment: Fixed the variable name also, was having some issues earlier with the timezones will try your answer

Comment: `new Interval(utc, convertedStartedAt).toPeriod()` was suggested on another stackoverflow post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you generate twice current date and time:
once here:

```
    DateTime testtime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("CET")).plusHours(2);
```

and once here:

```
    DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("CET"));
```

So the actual difference between is 29 minutes 59 seconds and 360 millis (in my test), rounded to 29 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it now, thanks to the comment of @Benoit. I changed the method `calculateTimeRemaining` to this:

```
public double calculateTimeDifference(String startedAt) {
    DateTime utc = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("CET"));

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    DateTime convertedStartedAt = formatter.parseDateTime(startedAt);

    Period period = new Period(utc, convertedStartedAt);
    double hours = period.getHours();
    double minutes = period.getMinutes();

    return hours + Math.round(minutes * 10.0/ 60)/10.0;
}
```

Thanks to all of you!